# PHPMailer SMTP Connect Error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, phpmailer

I'm trying to setup PHPMailer in AWS. It returns error saying **SMTP connect() failed.**

**Code**

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug =2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';
$mail->oauthUserEmail = "xxx@gmail.com";
$mail->oauthClientId = "client-key.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$mail->oauthClientSecret = "secretkey";
$mail->oauthRefreshToken = "refresh_token";
$mail->setFrom('tittuonnet@gmail.com', 'ParkIt');
$mail->addAddress("tittuhpd@gmail.com", "Tittu Varghese");
$mail->Subject = 'ParkIt - Verification Code';
$mail->Body = 'Please verify your account';

$mail->send();
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

**Debug log**

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP 22sm11056028qkv.52 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO server_domain_or_ip
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.157.255.58]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO server_domain_or_ip
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.157.255.58]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection 22sm11056028qkv.52 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP s191sm6833675qke.56 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO server_domain_or_ip
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.157.255.58]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO server_domain_or_ip
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.157.255.58]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection s191sm6833675qke.56 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

**AWS Security Rules**
[image: AWS Security Rules]

Comment: Well, your error log states `SMTP Error: Could not authenticate`. Have you set correct credentials?

Comment: Have you worked through [the Google xoauth2 guide in the PHPMailer wiki](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved my issue. I have found some useful resources during the process (which may cause similar issues during SMTP authentication.)

**Solution**
You have to include PHPMailerAutoload.php file to the code even if you are using composer.

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Join the group **[Allow Risky Access Permissions By Unreviewed Apps](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/risky-access-by-unreviewed-apps)** in order to execute unreviewed / development / single SMTP authenticated applications. You can read more about it from [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DuYM1jcy2v-NBNtdf9SLCVxOndslGAHQL0nBxSdt-MA/edit).

Comment: This is not true. If you're loading PHPMailer through composer (as you should be), you do not need to use the old autoloader - it doesn't exist in current PHPMailer anyway. If you do need it, it suggests you're not using composer correctly.